# If parent case is closed, close all related child cases - using flow builder

Tags: visual-workflow, case

Trying to do this with flow builder. Related cases are not being closed if I close a case. I need to also send a notification to the case manager when the child cases are closed.
Please help.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What context does the Flow run in? If it's a user context, does the user have read/edit access to the child Cases? Have you tried debugging the Flow and inspecting the result of those Get and Update elements?

Answer (score 0):

Your criteria for the Get Records is backwards. It should read "Parent Id Equals Id." However, your flow is unnecessarily complicated.

In the Start element, you can simply filter the flow to trigger only when the case is closed.

[image: Start Element using the Case object, with an entry criteria that the case is edited to the closed status.]

Next, you can use the Update Related Records element to select $Record.Cases, filtered by status not being closed (for efficiency), and then updating those records with the closed status.

[image: Update Related Records element for child cases that are not closed.]

Finally, the Notify Manager on Close box can just reference the record owner's manager Id.

Your flow will need to be slightly more complicated, as I'm not including any error handling or null checks, but this the basic design you can use to implement this logic efficiently.

As a side note, a query result will never be null.